# What does rsyslog do if it fills up a named pipe?

Tags: pipe, syslog, rsyslog, fifo

I'm working on a C application that is intended to monitor and process the output of rsyslog. My research shows that a way to do this is to create a named pipe and then create a new syslog target that points at that named pipe. My C application will then open this named pipe and read from it.

However, let's say my C application is not reading fast enough from the named pipe leading to a case where syslog fills up the fifo buffer. What exactly does syslog do? Does it create and maintain an internal buffer? Or does it just start discarding new messages?

My application is not super critical, so ideally syslog would just start discarding messages rather than start clogging up the system with buffered data or something.

Comment: See the rsyslog [white
paper](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/whitepapers/queues_analogy.html) and
[queue concepts](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/concepts/queues.html). 
In my testing, data logging to other output is not affected by one queue
being blocked.